# Why is 'where' an adverb and not a pronoun?

Tags: adverbs, pronouns

> **A**: Where are you going?
>   **B**: I am going to school.

*Where* took the place of school and something that takes the place of a noun is a pronoun. So, why isn't *where* a pronoun?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*Where* does not take the place of *school*, which is, as you say, a noun.

It takes the place of *to school*, which is a prepositional phrase acting in this sentence as <s>an adverb of directive location</s> a subject complement<s>ing</s> to the verb *go*.

> I am going [to school] → I am going [where] → [Where] are you going?

You may, if you like, consider *where* as an interrogative pro-<s>adverb</s>PP.

Comment: Apparently it's more accurately described as a pro–prepositional phrase, or simply as a [preposition](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/290930/why-when-how-and-where-are-not-interrogative-pronouns-why).

Comment: @sumelic Fersher; this was written before I grokked what's going on here. I've rewritten.

Answer (score 6):

*Where* is a fronted adverb which is also a **wh**-word.

Take a look at the following examples:

> 1. *You are going *New York*.

This is ungrammatical.  A noun representing a place can't directly follow *going*.  Instead, *going* can be followed by a prepositional phrase or an adverb:

> 2. You are going *to New York.*  (preposition phrase--okay)
>
> 3. You are going *quickly.*  (adverb--okay)

So what do we have in the following example?

> 4. You are going *there*.

It looks like an adverb to me.  There's no preposition, so it can't be a preposition phrase, and it's not a noun because we established (with example 1) that a noun would be ungrammatical.

Now let's replace *there* with *where*:

> 5. You are going *where*?

It still looks like an adverb to me.  We've established that a noun doesn't work in this position, so *where* isn't taking the place of a noun.  That means it can't be a pronoun.

Of course, example 5 is only allowed in limited circumstances.  Two examples are *reclamatory questions*, in which you're asking someone to repeat themselves, and *incredulity questions*, where you're expressing disbelief about what someone just said.  They also feature in situations that involve sustained questioning, such as in court or on a game show.  But outside those limited circumstances, *where* needs to be fronted, which means moving it to the front of the sentence:

> 6. **Where* you are going?  (ungrammatical; *you* and *are* must be inverted)
>  7. *Where* are you going?  (okay)

In 6, the **wh**-word is fronted; this is ungrammatical without subject-auxiliary inversion.  In 7, the subject and auxiliary are inverted, so it's grammatical again.

So it seems to me that the **wh**-word in this case is also a fronted adverb.

---

In this answer, the `*` symbol means I've identified the sentence as ungrammatical.

Comment: @Araucaria Will rectify, but please give me some time.  2013 snailboat needs to be bonked upside the head with a blunt object and dragged out to a shed.

Comment: @Araucaria I'm actually recovering from surgery right now and I am somewhat *ahem* medicated at the moment, so this might not be the best time for me to be editing stuff on Stack Exchange.  But I will come back to it :-)

Answer (score 1):

Well this is *indeed* a difficult question, but really interesting.

So,

First off, the question `Where are you going` doesn't always mean `to school`. Cause usually people don't know (yet) the answers to their questions. It could be `to work`, `to that building`, `to nowhere`, or even `I don't know`. So that doesn't make the `where` replace *exactly* the `school`.

### ***If*** the `where` is a pronoun:

True, a pronoun replaces a noun and its "form" is of that noun. Cause its function is to *substitute* the noun. By extension, a pronoun and the noun it replaces are **interchangeable**.

You do understand, that `where` in that *interrogative* sentence cannot be replaced by `to school`: `to school, are you going?`. Plus, you **cannot** say that a positive sentence replaces some interrogative one.
Even, in a positive sentence, `where` still **cannot** function as replacement (pronoun).

Replacing is something like this:

> I know **the place**.
>
> --> I know **that**.

While `where` acts like this (as an adverb):

> I know **the place**.
>
> --> I know **the place** (where) you went. (`where` qualifies the word `place`)

### ***When*** the `where` is an adverb:

Now, it makes more sense when you're calling the `where` an adverb. Here, an adverb, essentially, is a word that changes or qualifies the meaning of a verb, adjective, other adverb, clause, sentence or any other word or phrase.

So if my deduction is correct, the `where` there functions to qualify the "original" question (sentence) `are you going?`. Similarly, the rule works for the examples I wrote above.
More examples to ensure you:

> did you go yesterday?
>
> > where did you go yesterday?
>
> did you teach English?
>
> > where did you teach English?

Comment: Well, you have to replace "where" with an equivalent interrogative phrase to keep the overall sentence a question: "[to **what place**] are you going?"

Answer (score 0):

“Where” is usually an adverb, but in some cases, it can be pronoun. When “where” is the object of a preposition, it is a pronoun. For instance, in  the question,

> “Where are you from?”

which can be reordered as

> “From where are you?”

“**where**” is the object of the preposition “**from**”. An answer to that question could be,

> “I am from the United States.”

“the United States” takes the place of “where”, which makes it a pronoun. However, in your sentence, “Where are you going?”, to which a possible answer could be, “I am going to school,” the entire prepositional phrase “to school” takes the place of “where”, and “to school” is an adverbial phrase modifying the verb “am going”. This makes “where” and adverb instead of a pronoun. So yes, “where” can be a pronoun, but usually when it is the object of a preposition. Otherwise, it is most likely an adverb.