# Relative adverbs: when vs where

Tags: grammaticality, adverbs, relative-adverbs

Source: p 39, *The Law of Contract*, 5 ed (2012), by O’Sullivan and Hilliard

> 2.83. ... We have seen that the general rule is that displaying goods in shops only constitutes an invitation to treat, although there are good reasons
>   for taking a diff erent approach (paras 2.22–2.23). However, what of a typical
>   website that allows the customer to select the item, enter his payment details and
>   seemingly conclude the agreement online. In this situation, then (absent the terms
>   and conditions of the site providing to the contrary) it is suggested that it is clear
>   that a contract has been concluded ... The
>   natural inference is that `a deal has been concluded`, **as where** you get through the
>   checkout at a supermarket and have paid for the goods. You would not expect in
>   these circumstances for the seller to be able to pull out.

What are the similarities and differences? Why not **as when**? The [relative adverb](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/10480/8712) modifies [the exact time that] 'a deal has been concluded', which is NOT  'a place, location, or space' as required below?

> - [(Source)](http://grammar.about.com/od/rs/g/relativeadverbterm.htm)  "The relative adverb **when** is used to modify a noun phrase of time. Such noun phrases include nouns that denote periods of time such as, day, week, hour, minute, month, year, and similar events.
> - [The relative adverb **where**](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/33940/8712) is used to modify a noun phrase of **place, location, or space**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Where** can also be used to indicate a *situation*, rather than just a *location*. The same goes for *there*; it is used to indicate a *location*, but by extension also a *situation*, a description of what happens, rather than the exact place where it happens:

> Imagine a situation *where* the customer refuses to pay.
>   We have all been *there*: it's your friends birthday, and you forgot about it.
>   So, what about the case *where* more than one person shows interest in the offer?

Have a look, for instance, at this well-known idiom (from [Cambridge](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/where-there-s-a-will-there-s-a-way)):

> **where there's a will there's a way**
>   (saying) used to mean that if you are determined enough, you can find a way to achieve what you want, even if it is very difficult

Notice that in the explanation, *if* is used with this meaning: *when* you want it, *then* it is possible.