# Why has the writer used "where" in the sentence in bold?

Tags: grammar, meaning-in-context, grammaticality-in-context

> Sometimes his wife got this look **where she pinched her brows together and bit her lower lip and stared down at something**.when he saw her like this he knew he should keep his mouth shut, but he never did. Actually it made him talk more. She had that look now.

I think it sould be written:...**when** she pinched her brows...

It is new to me to use "where" in such a sentence like this one.

Thank before hand for your help.

This context is from a short story named: Say Yes by Tobias Wolff.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Relative adverbs: when vs where](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/38442/relative-adverbs-when-vs-where)

Comment: Note that we often use the "spatial" localizer ***where*** to reference ***situations***, and this sometimes extends to ***times*** when specific situations arise. In your cited context, the highlighted adjectival clause further defines the situation where his wife *got a certain look / presented a specific facial expression*, so idiomatically ***where*** is fine (***when*** is also quite acceptable in this exact context, but probably less common).