# Is the sentence "This is the place where I recommend to you" incorrect?

Tags: word-choice, adverbs, relative-pronouns

A person says that the sentence "this is the place where I recommend to you" isn't correct but "this is the place which I recommend to you" is correct.

Is this right?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, that person is right. The first sentence might be fixed this way, if we wanted to retain 'where':

> This is the place where I recommend having your lunch.

I googled around, and the matter seems to be with the grammatical role of "where". In your example, it seems to work as an adverb.

The word "which" works as a relative pronoun referring to "the place".

> I recommend to you (what? **which** place?) this place. [OKAY]
>   I recommend to you (**where**?) this place. [WRONG]
>   I recommend having your lunch (**where**?) in this place. [OKAY]

---

P.S. "Where" is classified as part of the so-called "WH-adverbs":

> A special subclass of adverbs includes a set of words beginning with wh-. The most common are *when, where*, and *why*, though the set also includes *whence, whereby, wherein*, and *whereupon*. To this set we add the word *how*, and we refer to the whole set as WH-ADVERBS. ([The Internet Grammar of English](http://www.ucl.ac.uk/internet-grammar/adverbs/wh.htm))

Related questions:

- [Why is 'where' an adverb and not a pronoun?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/10480/why-is-where-an-adverb-and-not-a-pronoun)

---

P.S. I [was advised](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/28050798#28050798) to change my answer, because the verb "recommend" has some nuances of usage:

> Be Careful!
>   Don't say that you 'recommend someone' a particular action. Don't say, for example, 'I recommend you a visit to Paris'. Say 'I recommend a visit to Paris', 'I recommend visiting Paris', or 'I recommend that you visit Paris'. ([FreeDictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/recommend))

Maybe a native speaker will post an add-on answer explaining the best way to use 'recommend' in your sentence.

Comment: @YuuichiTam - you're welcome!

Answer (score 2):

It may be better to just omit the "which" since it is unnecessary so your sentence remains simpler:

This is the place I recommend to you.

Comment: When  can I omit which as unnecessary and when I can not ? What is the rule here plz?

Comment: Consider: You went to the place which is far. This sentence requires which or it'll sound awkward.